# Survey Using Javascript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

so currently I am trying to display different images for each radio button checked. each question has two answers each and the users are to choose between either and in the end, there is a submit button (like any other form). I want to be able to display images for each certain checked radio button. so for example, if each of the question they picked the first answer and press submit, it would display picture 1, if they were to pick the first answer for all besides the last question, it would display a different picture, and so on (so for each combination of results = different picture). thanks

```js
function myFunction() {
 var tops = document.getElementsByName('tops');
 var str =' ';
 for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  if (tops[i].checked === true) {
   str += tops[i].value + " ";
  }
 }
 alert(str);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Quiz Yourself! </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="deer">
<h1 style="font-size: 120px; text-align: center; border: 3px solid black; background-color: white;"> Quiz Yourself! </h1>
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/70/Solid_white.svg/2000px-Solid_white.svg.png" class="pop">
<h3> 1. Shows or Movies? </h3>
<form class="ok">
<input type="radio" name="tops" value="Shows" checked> Shows <br>
<input type="radio" name="tops" value="Movies"> Movies <br>
</form>
<h3> 2. Apple or Windows? </h3>
<form class="ok">
<input type="radio" name="tops" value="Apple" checked> Apple <br>
<input type="radio" name="tops" value="Windows"> Windows <br>
</form>
<h3> 3. Pink or Blue? </h3>
<form class="ok">
<input type="radio" name="tops" value="Pink" checked> Pink <br>
<input type="radio" name="tops" value="Blue"> Blue <br>
</form>
<h3> 4. Basketball or Football? </h3>
<form class="ok">
<input type="radio" name="tops" value="Basketball" checked> Basketball <br>
<input type="radio" name="tops" value="Football"> Football <br>
</form>
<h3> 5. Phone Call or Texting Type of Person? </h3>
<form class="ok">
<input type="radio" name="tops" value="Phone Call" checked> Phone Call <br>
<input type="radio" name="tops" value="Texting"> Texting <br>
</form>
<h3> 6. Cake or Pie? </h3>
<form class="ok">
<input type="radio" name="tops" value="Cake" checked> Cake <br>
<input type="radio" name="tops" value="Pie"> Pie <br>
</form>
<h3> 7. Big Party or Small Gathering? </h3>
<form class="ok">
<input type="radio" name="tops" value="Big Party" checked> Big Party <br>
<input type="radio" name="tops" value="Small Gathering"> Small Gathering <br>
</form>
<h3> 8. Sneakers or Sandals? </h3>
<form class="ok">
<input type="radio" name="tops" value="Sneakers" checked> Sneakers <br>
<input type="radio" name="tops" value="Sandals"> Sandals <br>
</form>
<h3> 9. Gold or Silver? </h3>
<form class="ok">
<input type="radio" name="tops" value="Gold" checked> Gold <br>
<input type="radio" name="tops" value="Silver"> Silver <br>
</form>
<h3> 10. Pen or Pencil? </h3>
<form class="ok">
<input type="radio" name="tops" value="Pen" checked> Pen <br>
<input type="radio" name="tops" value="Pencil"> Pencil <br>
</form>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<button onclick="myFunction();return false;" class="yes"> Submit </button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed that all of the question can only have 2 choices. 
I also assumed that you want to display the image in a `<img src='...' />` dom element.

In that case, I have modified your code to work as follows:

a- begin with `str` empty string

b- check the first question, the first option. If it is checked, append `a` to `str`. If it is unchecked then append `b`. There is no need to check the second option. So, lets skip it

c- loop until all question have been iterated (`tops.length`) not just '20'. You might decided to add more or remove questions. So it is better to rely on `tops.length`.

d- Append a proper image file extension to the string obtained above. ie: `.png/.jpg/etc`.

e- set the property `src` of the result image as described above.

```js
var results = {
     "aaaaaaaaaa":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/EDzLx3hkli0/maxresdefault.jpg",
     "aaaaaaaaab":"https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/07/28/23/34/fantasy-picture-2550222_960_720.jpg",
     "bbbbbbbbbb":"http://your.image.link/here.png"
}
// you need to fill the other values.

function myFunction() {
 var tops = document.getElementsByName('tops');
 var str ='';
  
  // assuming each question only has 2 choices, we can
  // safely iterate through all question by evaluating
  // the first option of each question and skipping the
  // second option, since, if the first option is checked
  // then the other option is not, and vice versa
  
  for (i = 0; i < tops.length; i+=2) {
    str += (tops[i].checked)? 'a':'b';   // I choose 'a' for checked, and 'b' for unchecked
 }
  
  // after the loop, if all questions were answered by the first option, you will get
  // 'aaaaaaaaaa' and if all of them selected the second option, you will get 'bbbbbbbbbb'
  

  var link = results[str];   // lookup for the image path
  
  var img = document.getElementById("result");
  img.alt = link;
  img.src = link;
 alert(str + "="  + link);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Quiz Yourself! </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="deer">
<h3> 1. Shows or Movies? </h3>
<form class="ok">
<input type="radio" name="tops" value="Shows" checked> Shows <br>
<input type="radio" name="tops" value="Movies"> Movies <br>
</form>
<h3> 2. Apple or Windows? </h3>
<form class="ok">
<input type="radio" name="tops" value="Apple" checked> Apple <br>
<input type="radio" name="tops" value="Windows"> Windows <br>
</form>
<h3> 3. Pink or Blue? </h3>
<form class="ok">
<input type="radio" name="tops" value="Pink" checked> Pink <br>
<input type="radio" name="tops" value="Blue"> Blue <br>
</form>
<h3> 4. Basketball or Football? </h3>
<form class="ok">
<input type="radio" name="tops" value="Basketball" checked> Basketball <br>
<input type="radio" name="tops" value="Football"> Football <br>
</form>
<h3> 5. Phone Call or Texting Type of Person? </h3>
<form class="ok">
<input type="radio" name="tops" value="Phone Call" checked> Phone Call <br>
<input type="radio" name="tops" value="Texting"> Texting <br>
</form>
<h3> 6. Cake or Pie? </h3>
<form class="ok">
<input type="radio" name="tops" value="Cake" checked> Cake <br>
<input type="radio" name="tops" value="Pie"> Pie <br>
</form>
<h3> 7. Big Party or Small Gathering? </h3>
<form class="ok">
<input type="radio" name="tops" value="Big Party" checked> Big Party <br>
<input type="radio" name="tops" value="Small Gathering"> Small Gathering <br>
</form>
<h3> 8. Sneakers or Sandals? </h3>
<form class="ok">
<input type="radio" name="tops" value="Sneakers" checked> Sneakers <br>
<input type="radio" name="tops" value="Sandals"> Sandals <br>
</form>
<h3> 9. Gold or Silver? </h3>
<form class="ok">
<input type="radio" name="tops" value="Gold" checked> Gold <br>
<input type="radio" name="tops" value="Silver"> Silver <br>
</form>
<h3> 10. Pen or Pencil? </h3>
<form class="ok">
<input type="radio" name="tops" value="Pen" checked> Pen <br>
<input type="radio" name="tops" value="Pencil"> Pencil <br>
</form>
<br>
<br>
<img id="result" alt="Result Image here" text="Result Image Here" />
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<button onclick="myFunction();return false;" class="yes"> Submit </button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: perfectly what I wanted, and (sorry to bother again), where do I enter the source of all the images (i'm guessing more than 50 haha) that will be the result of each submissions? do I enter it in the html form or where?

Comment: for ex, do I put it in <img id="result" alt="pic1.png, pic2.png, pic3.png"? i'm a little lost on adding the images

Comment: I added an image at the bottom (before submit button) where you can display the image. But you can move it anywhere you like. You need to have as many files as necessary to display all possible results.

Comment: There is not need to do anything with HTML part. Javascript will automatically set the src attribute of the result image to a single value `aaaaaaaaaa.png` for example. You can not set multiple images at once. Only one value is allowed

Comment: @LilyLe also, there is no need to update `alt=` property. It is just for display only. I put it so that if the image link is broken, the user will understand that there is supposed to be an image here

Comment: @LilyLe If you still need help, please let me know. Otherwise, if my answer helped you, please accept and upvote it. Thanks

Comment: i'm still confused, so if I want this picture > i.ytimg.com/vi/EDzLx3hkli0/maxresdefault.jpg assigned for aaaaaaaaaa.jpg, static1.squarespace.com/static/51b3dc8ee4b051b96ceb10de/t/… for abaaaaaaaa.jpg, and cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/07/28/23/34/… for aabaaaaaaa.jpg, where do I insert the in the code?

Comment: I updated my answer. You need to define a lookup table for all possible answers. See the top of my answers for the variable: `results` josn object. @LilyLe

Comment: you could have those images, with the appropriate filenames (e.g. aaaaaaaaa.jpg) in the same folder as your html file (or in a sub folder e.g. images/aaaaaaaaa.jpg then your `str` would begin with 'images/') so that when the javascript builds the str, then `img.src = str` sets that string as the source (location/address) for the image.

Comment: when I try the first option for all answers and press submit, I get an alert that says "aaaaaaaaaa=undefined". what's happening?

Comment: @LilyLe make sure when you define `str` variable that it starts blank `var str='';` not `var str=' ';` dont start with a space

Comment: ah! I got it now, thanks for your help. if I need help with anything else, is there another way I can contact you?

Comment: @LilyLe do you use whatsapp?

Comment: hi! sorry for the late reply - no I don't

Comment: @Ahmad hey, so you know how you put alert(str + "=" + link)? Is there any way you can make it alert that "Your assigned picture is" + assigned name? I'll assign each of the picture a name, but like assigning a picture to each submission, how do I also assign a certain text WITH the picture? (either with the alert, or like on top of the picture)

Comment: It's kind of confusing but I'm trying to assign text with the picture for each assigned, though each text will be different for each submission. For example, aaaaaaaaaa submission will give back a Pikachu picture, but I also want it to alert "You've gotten" + "Pikachu". For aaaaaaaaab, submission will give out another picture and the alert would be "You've gotten" + "another assigned name here".

Comment: @LilyLe Hi. could you send that codepen link again here?

Comment: @LilyLe Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/almutawa/pen/bOGgam) for generating aaaaaaaaaa to bbbbbbbbbb automatically